# How can QString::toInt() convert a string that's not numeric?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm reading one of my textbooks that does a poor job of explaining the code it introduces. Here the sample code:

```
int choice;
QString response;
do {
 cout << READ << ". Read data from a file.\n"
 << ADD << ". Add items to the Library.\n"
 << FIND << ". Find and display an item.\n"
 << REMOVE << ". Remove an item from the Library.\n"
 << SAVE << ". Save the Library list to a file.\n"
 << LIST << ". Brief listing of Library items.\n"
 << QUIT << ". Exit from this program.\n"
 << "Your choice: " << flush;
 response = cin.readLine();
 choice = response.toInt();
} while(choice < READ or choice > QUIT)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt),

> Returns 0 if the conversion fails.

That means, if string is not numeric, it will return 0.